Return data in the same order that I have inserted it with Sqlite3
I'm working with, I think, the lastest version of Sqlite and C++. I have a table with data, and I need to return this data in the order I inserted it.
Do I have any guarantee that the columns will always be returned in this order?

Maybe I must add another column to set the order and use ORDER BY:



I have a table with data, and I need to return this data in the order I inserted it.

Then you must have a column with a number or timestamp you would use for order by.
If you live on SQLite and you do not delete any rows from the table, than you can use an automatic field ROWID and do order by rowid. Read here about this field: https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html
But since the order of rowid can be ruined by deletion-insertion and by direct modifying of the field - it would still be better to just add into your table a field for sorting.

Do I have any guarantee that the columns will always be returned in this order?

Yes. As long as you do no alter table, the select * will always return columns in the same order.
